# Why won't the "Unlock Keyring" window go away?

Tags: 16.04, gnome-keyring

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS and whenever I'm logged in, I get this window:

[image: Unlock Keyring]

I type in my password, and it disappears and comes back a second later.  After ten attempts at typing in my password, it finally goes away.  I tried pressing cancel, but its the same result.  I wouldn't mind so much if it didn't take away focus from other windows.  When I open Chrome, I am typing a URL to visit, and the "Unlock Keyring" window pops up again and won't let me do anything until I manage to get rid of it.  How can I keep this thing away?

Comment: chrome and other apt store keys in the keyring. when these apps need the key you have to unlock the keyring for them

Comment: @ravery ok so how do I get rid of it?

Comment: are you using autologin? all the solutins I see say to turn off autologin, or set the keyring password to blank

Comment: @ravery I don't know what autologin is.

Comment: it allows you automatically login instead of typing password

Comment: @ravery no I'm not using autologin.  I have a strong password.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66169/discussion-between-ravery-and-curtice-gough).